# MySQL Workbench Data Migration fails

Tags: mysql-workbench

I want to migrate the schema and data from the Amazon Mysql service to local MySql instance running in docker. the connections work fine (source and target) but the during the migration it always fail with the following log:

```
- Retrieving function sourcedb.doOverlap...
- Reverse engineering sourcedb.doOverlap...

    Reverse engineering sourcedb.doOverlap ...
    A task has failed executing
    



    Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_copy_progress.py", line 155, in thread_work
            self.func()
          File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/db_copy_progress.py", line 581, in _rev_eng_schema
            self.main.plan.migrationSource.reverseEngineer()
          File "/usr/lib/mysql-workbench/modules/migration.py", line 364, in reverseEngineer
            self.state.sourceCatalog = self._rev_eng_module.reverseEngineer(self.connection, self.selectedCatalogName, self.selectedSchemataNames, self.state.applicationData)
        SystemError: TypeError("can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLRE.reverseEngineer
        ERROR: Reverse Engineering: TypeError("can only concatenate str (not "NoneType") to str"): error calling Python module function DbMySQLRE.reverseEngineer
        Failed
```

Does anyone know what's wrong with the data migration? I also tried schema transfer but the same error occurs.

Comment: Check if your mysql user has all privileges granted

Comment: The error comes from within mysql workbench's code and it is not an sql related error, but a python one. You nees to raise this as a bug with mysql.